# How to reduce the time of the transition of the hovering header when scroll

Tags: javascript, css

in this site https://gptrading.it/ i would like to change the time of the transition of the header background hover on scroll. It starts between like two scroll, i would like to make it start right after the first scroll. How can i achive that?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide us with a code we can help you. Otherwise it is impossible to know what are you doing exactly.

In advance, it seems that is something related to `window.offset()` in your javascript function.

EDIT

I have search on your project through JS files. It seems that you are creating a wordpress project. So often the themes you download to install on your wordpress include a theme.js. Here is the path of your theme JS file:

https://gptrading.it/wp-content/themes/techno/assets/js/theme.js?ver=3.2.4

I paste following the code that this file is using to turn the navigation bar into sticky:

```
// 6.EM STIKY NAV
var headers1 = $('.trp_nav_area');
$(window).on('scroll', function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        headers1.addClass('hbg2');
    } else {
        headers1.removeClass('hbg2');
    }

});
```

Just search on this file and replace the value `$(window).scrollTop() > 200` with your preference (as you say `0`). Remeber that this value is mesured in PX.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really don't have much knowledge of JavaScript, i'm a front-end developer that work much with html and css. If you can guide me where to find the code that you need to clarify the situation, I would be grateful.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I just take a quick look into your project through console. I think this is what you need in order to get the desired effect. Just try to do it, if it doesn't work, just come back and will take another look.

Comment: Great!, it worked, thank you soo much!

Comment: I'm glad to hear!